# Why does gtkmm row get_value not work?

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

With this code:

```cpp
size = 100;
uint64_t work;
row.get_value(3, work);
cout << "value was " << work << endl;
work += size;
cout << "value set to " << work << endl;
row.set_value(3, work);
row.get_value(3, work);
cout << "value now " << work << endl;
```

I expect this output:

```
value was 0
value set to 100
value now 100
```

but I get:

```
value was 0
value set to 100
value now 0
```

The updated value, 100, does display correctly in the tree view widget, I just cannot read it with get_value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the documentation for `set_value()`; are you sure `row` still points to the same row afterward?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was the uint64_t; row[3] was defined (in Glade) as a guint, the work variable must match that type exactly or get_value will not work.